# My attempts to install json using "gem install json" don't seem to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rubygems, chef-infra

When I attempt to run a script to set up my workspace, I get this error

```
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find json (<= 1.6.1, >= 1.4.4) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, bundler-1.1.5, bunny-0.7.9, chef-10.14.4, erubis-2.7.0, highline-1.6.15, io-console-0.3, ipaddress-0.8.0, jruby-pageant-1.1.1, json-1.8.1, mime-types-1.19, minitest-2.5.1, mixlib-authentication-1.3.0, mixlib-cli-1.2.2, mixlib-config-1.1.2, mixlib-log-1.4.1, mixlib-shellout-1.1.0, moneta-0.6.0, net-ssh-2.2.2, net-ssh-gateway-1.1.0, net-ssh-multi-1.1, ohai-6.14.0, polyglot-0.3.3, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4, rest-client-1.6.7, systemu-2.5.2, treetop-1.4.10, uuidtools-2.1.3, yajl-ruby-1.1.0] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:777:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `each'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:766:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:750:in `activate'
    from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1232:in `gem'
    from /opt/chef/bin/chef-solo:22:in `<main>'
you have a different version of chef installed and we don't support uninstalling them with this script, we only support version 10.14.4
```

Which I'm assuming means I need a json version between 1.4.4 and 1.6.1, so I ran this statement

```
gem install json -v 1.6.1
```

Which spits out this....

```
WARNING:  Error fetching data: Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) (https://gem.vistacore.us:8443/gem/specs.4.8.gz)
WARNING:  Error fetching data: Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) (https://nexus.vistacore.us:8443/gem/specs.4.8.gz)
Fetching: json-1.6.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed json-1.6.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for json-1.6.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for json-1.6.1...
```

But when I try to rerun my workspace script, I get the first error again. It's as if nothing's been installed. What's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the `json` gem in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: I don't have a GemFile directory but I have a bunch of GemFiles and opening them up show that some of them have json 1.8.1, while other's don't seem too have it.

Comment: Did you `require "json"`?

Comment: Can you please run `ruby -v` and `which ruby` and paste the output here ?

Comment: @sethvargo I'm not sure what you mean by require "json"

Comment: @Nax I got "ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]" and "/opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby"

Comment: Ok, so it's not a misconfigured rvm install. Do your script/project use bundle or something similar?

Comment: Yes, they use bundle

Comment: There are multiple Rubies in play here - the system one and `/opt/chef/embedded/`

Comment: What happen if you run `bundle install` while you are in the project directory?

Comment: @Nax It says gem file not found

Comment: How did you get this rails project that has no `Gemfile`?

Comment: I thought running the workspace set up script was supposed to install the gem files?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what a `Gemfile` is. It is a single file where you define the gems you plan on using for your project. http://bundler.io/gemfile.html for some information.

Answer (score 0):

First, lets list all your versions of ruby as you might have multiple versions

```
$ rvm list ruby
```

Second, check your gem version as well, if the versions dont match up with what your program wants than get rid of that stuff and put the version it wants or do a

```
$ rvm use (foo)
```

**After you view your gem version**

```
$ gem --version
```

Check all your env variables for stuff like `$GEM_HOME` etc.

Sometimes the native extensions are missed just because your env variables might be off. After you fix all that, you'll be good, just install the json gem.

```
$ gem install json
```

**No need to specify the version it will automatically pull the version needed.**

Remember, rubygem installs gems based on its own version and the version of rubygem you have installed by rvm is based on the ruby version installed by rvm so it all goes back to what version of ruby & rubygems rvm put on your machine at the time of your installation. If the rubygem and ruby version is correct, then it will automatically pull the json gem that is compatible with your program when you install it, adding your env variables properly assist to build native extensions and aid your program in seeing everything. I hope this helped shed some light on things.

Comment: no need to keep changing your name in the answer; it has no relevance.  If you want to change your name, update your profile name.

Answer (score 0):

From the actual error

You have a different version of chef installed and we don't support uninstalling them with this script, we only support version 10.14.4

I would try uninstalling your version and then installing using chef 10.14.4